# Multiple definition of even with header gaurd

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a header file:

```
#ifndef DATA_HPP
#define DATA_HPP

#include <cstdint>

namespace f {
namespace t {
namespace e {

uint32_t a = 99;

class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
};

}
}
}
#endif
```

With CPP file try.cpp:

```
#include "try.hpp"

namespace f {
namespace t {
namespace e {

Test::Test()
{
}
Test::~Test()
{
}

}
}
}
```

And the main file - main.cpp:

```
#include "try.hpp"

int main()
{
f::t::e::Test a;
}
```

But when I compile my code:

```
c++ --std=c++11 try.cpp main.cpp
```

I get below error:

```
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `f::t::e::a'
try.cpp:(.data+0x0): first defined here
```

I already have the header file guard - so why the error is being reported and how can I fix it?

Comment: Header guard only protects against multiple inclusion of header files in the same [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). It doesn't protect against multiple definitions in different translation units.

Comment: Seems like the endif in CPP file was a TYPO issues - remove the same

Comment: Now your include guard is missing the `#endif` completely

Comment: Edited and added

Comment: #define DATA_HPP is specific to a given translation unit where the header file is included. So, when the same header file is included in a different translation unit they are read and included.